# Why is this question being downvoted?

Tags: support, site-scope, voting

I asked a question about [which US phone carriers allows its users to use one of iOS' features](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/437749/which-us-carriers-offer-voicemail-transcription), and it got downvoted.

Apple has a [Discussion page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204039) about it, but it seems incomplete.

People in the comments seem confused by the difference between "Visual Voicemail" (the Voicemail tab in your Phone app) and Voicemail Transcription (a per-carrier feature enabling transcription of voicemails inside the Visual Voicemail app).

Is that why the question was downvoted?

I thought it was because it was partly about carrier-related features but there is a Hashtag "phone-carrier" so I thought it validated the question.

Answer (score 1):

It‘s sometimes hard to guess why some posts gather downvotes and others don‘t, and if downvoters don‘t leave a comment it isn‘t easy to improve.

One thing I learned over the years participating on AD is that the community tends to downvote questions which are border-line on-topic but seem to lack research. Also, questions which basically could be entered directly in the search engine of your choice tend to attract downvotes. And, to be honest, "Is there an updated list of US Carriers that offer the Voicemail Transcription where I could compare plan prices?" reads like something which indeed could be searched for.

Comment: I have searched for an answer to that question using search engines but haven’t found any answer so far…

Comment: FWIW that seems an awful lot like a cross between "not about Apple software or hardware" and "seems to lack research." As it is asking a question about what carrier to use for a specific feature **and** something that could be answered by searching and/or calling the carrier's customer support at the phone companies available to you.